# Pausing between methods

Tags: android, mysql, sms, refresh

This is my first attempt at developing in java/android.

I have created an app that reads from a database, (MySQL) it retrieves a record, and based on the values in the record and sends 4 SMS's to a second device.

After it has sent the SMS's, it updates the database the second device which runs the same app, connects to the database, and does the same, again updating the database.

Add 10 devices to the mix, all connecting to the database, retrieving values, and sending messages.

When the last device connects, it updates the record of the first device, and, so, when the first device connects again, it sees that the last device has sent it's messages, and then, sends another batch of messages, before clearing the database, and clearing the values in the database.

My first issue is this, I have a single activity that retrieves the device number via a USSD code, which when completed, calls a method to read the data so that it can start sending, however, I have no way of telling the device to connect to the database at intervals, i.e. if device 1 has not completed sending messages, device two will connect, see that it must not yet send, and then, just stays in that state. I need the device to connect at intervals, without any user intervention.

Is this possible?

If I exit the app on a device, and restart it, it connects, sees that it's record has been updated, and does the next batch of sending.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run a method periodically, you can do something like this:

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {

        // Your code here

        // run again after 10 s
        handler.postDelayed(this, 10000);
      }
    }, 10000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could append something to the end(or beginning) of the last message, that tells the second device it is the last message.

EX: 
device 1:
add "%" to the beginning of the last text

device 2:

```
if(msg.CharAt(0)=='%')
{
 //this is the last message
 // do task
{
```

The other option I see, is that since you're updating the database. You could poll the database on the second device and only start sending messages once the previous device finished.

something like:

```
while(!device1Finished)
{
}
sendMessages();
```